# Clone a JS object except of a key value array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, clone

I have an object:

```
const inputsCustomer = {
  title: "customer information",
  inputs: [
    { key: "customerAccount" },
    { key: "customerCity" }
  ]
};
```

I want to duplicate this object with out { key: "customerAccount" }.

Expected cloned object:

```
const newInputsCustomer = {
  title: "customer information",
  inputs: [
    { key: "customerCity" }
  ]
};
```

I've been trying with destructuring but haven't manage to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]  (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: can't you clone, then filter? can you show your attempt ([mcve])

Comment: Just clone the whole thing, then remove that one piece of data you don't want by shifting it out of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread syntax to copy over the object, then use `Array#filter` to keep only the elements without the specified key.

```js
const inputsCustomer = {
  title: "customer information",
  inputs: [
    { key: "customerAccount" },
    { key: "customerCity" }
  ]
};
let res = {...inputsCustomer, inputs: 
  inputsCustomer.inputs.filter(x => x.key !== 'customerAccount')};
console.log(res);
```